# Is this a beta distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm currently implementing something from a paper and at one point it describes using a beta distribution of the form:

$Prob(p) = (n + 1)Bi(n, p; m)$ where $Bi$ is the binomial distribution, $n$ and $m$ are observed values, $p$ is a naive guess of $m/n$, and $(n + 1)$ is to ensure that the distribution is normalized.

As this notation doesn't resemble a beta distribution nor a beta-binomial distribution, I'm rather confused. Using it as is, for sufficiently large $n$, will return probabilities $\geq$ 1 obviously.

Assuming that the above is correct, how can one use it in a similar way to a beta distribution? Or is there something else I need to do?

Thanks!

(Note: I'm terrible when it comes to understanding distributions, so I think I've missed something fundamental here.)

Comment: These are densities, not probabilities, hence being $\gt1$ is not a problem. And yes, this is the Beta $(m+1,n-m+1)$ density, just write down explicitely your $\Pr(p)$.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks a lot!! Still a touch confused about how to calculate Pr(p) from this.

Comment: ?? The density of p is *given*. Do you know what is Bi(n,p;m)?

Comment: @Did Well, yes. So I'm assuming I either take the integral of (n+1)Bi(n,p;m) or determine the cdf of Beta(m+1, n-m+1) for this to be of any use to me?  (Again, I'm sure I'm missing some fundamentals of distributions.)